# How to solve an RSA decryption problem using subsitution?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I am having a lot of trouble understanding the following RSA question,

$A$ and $B$ use RSA with the same $n=47 \cdot 71$, and $e_A= 11$,  $e_B= 9$, respectively.

$A$ knows $n$, $d_A, e_A, e_B$ only. Show how $A$ can read `234` sent by $B$.

Here is my logic,

$$\varphi(n) = (47-1)(71-1) = 3220$$

Generally, we would want to find dB so we can solve $234^{d_B} \bmod (\varphi(n))$ in order to get the original message.

Here however $A$ does not know $d_B$ so we can't do that, so how could we solve such a problem?

I have only learnt the basics of RSA encryption so I am not sure how to proceed, I know we can calculate $d_A$ quite easily since $e_A.d_A = 1\bmod(\varphi)$ and so $d_A = 11^{-1} \bmod 3220$, 
which gives $d_A = 1171$. I just dont see how that is helpful in finding $d_B$

The problem above can only be solved using a substitute for $\phi(n)$, could someone explain how we substitute $\varphi(n)$ to solve this.

Comment: A knows how to factor $n$ and knows $e_B$.  This dictates $d_B$ via the description of the algorithm.

Comment: Your Phi's should be $\varphi(n)$.

Comment: HI Moo, you can do that, its just for this particular question that is not allowed, you have to solve it using a substitute for $\phi(n)$, I dont understand how to do that so I asked here

Comment: Well, they are using same modulus and this is insecure in RSA even [a single prime sharing](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76757/18298). One knows the $e_B$ since it is public than use $e_B d_B = 1 \bmod \varphi$. One can calculate $d_B$ with the usual ExtGCD.

Comment: Hi kelalaka, the question could be easily solved by doing that, but I am asking how to solve if that method is not available. There is another way to solve this problem using subsitution which is why I made this post.

Comment: @kelalaka you want modulo $\phi(n)$, in your last computations, I think.

Comment: @Padwas if you need to poke someone append @ to their nicknames. We know that Alice(A) knows $e_A,e_B,p,q,n$ with 

$$e_a \cdot d_A \equiv 1 \pmod \varphi(n)$$

Alice find $x$ such that $x e_a = e_b$ then calculates $$e_a \cdot x \cdot d_A \cdot x^{-1} \equiv 1 \pmod \varphi(n)$$

$$e_B \cdot d_B \equiv 1 \pmod \varphi(n)$$

Comment: @HennoBrandsma yes, corrected. The substitution was not clear to me, so I've made a little workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If A knows the common $n$, his own $d_a, e_a$ and the public exponent $e_b$, then there are several routes:

- A can factor $n$ because he knows both $e_a$ and $d_a$ (standard fact) and so knows $\phi(n)$. Weirdly enough your exercise already gives you the factorisation, which trivialises the exercise completely. $d_b$ is then trivially computable, and A can decrypt B's message. In other comments you say this is "not allowed" but it's all computable from the data that is given so I hold it *is* allowed (and is probably the intended solution by the proposer).
- Because $n$ is trivially small you can compute $x^{e_b} \pmod {n}$ for all $x < n$ until we have a match for $243$. This gives $x=1550$ almost instantly ( I tried). This doesn't even need the fact that A and B have the same modulus, which strengthens my assertion that we do need the factorisation of $n$ or equivalently the knowledge of $\phi(n)$ that A has.